Accidentally removed "/usr/bin/solc" after installation, now no command work
Unfortunatly, meanwhile I was trying to get the latest solidity version, i deleted the /usr/bin/solc folder, and now I can non longer run any script (i.e. solc --version or  --help)
Can someone help me? Thank you
I already tried to re install via npm install -g solc
And also other methods, but I always get that I'm up to date, nothing to update...

I don't think npm install -g installs in /usr/bin but I could be wrong. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/315168

/usr/bin/solc is a normal UNIX binary in a normal path.
You installed solc somehow and you can get this binary again by simply reinstalling.

Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately even if i re-install solc, the usr/bin/solc is still missing.

Please edit the question and explain how do you reinstall.

Done, i edited the question

After a new installation and a reboot I was able to run solc again. Thank you.
